# Set Background Image from Custom Meta in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, metadata, background-image

I'm trying to get the home page of a WordPress theme I am building to change the background image on refresh based on 3 potential background images.

Each image is considered part of a larger "case study" that has a title, link, text, etc.
The case study fields are created through custom meta boxes on the home page. (I am using this to simplify the meta box creation process: https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress).

Long story short, the client wants 3 case studies on the home page to have corresponding background images.  This is why I didn't use the featured image functionality, as each background goes with specific meta data.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to get the meta ID of the chosen background image and use that to set the background CSS.

Here is what I have so far:

```
/**
 * Home Page Case Randomizer
 */

$GLOBALS['_home_case_number'] = rand(1, 3);


function home_case_number() {

   if ( is_front_page() ) :  // checks whether this is the home page

    // get the meta image
$attachment_image = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_home_case_background_' . $_home_case_number, true );
```

This is where I get confused.  The above returns the appropriate `image.jpg` file.  How do I massage this to work with the below code?

The below code is adapted from  http://s2webpress.com/responsive-featured-image-function-in-wordpress-themes/, and I'd like to use it to make sure I'm serving images responsively.

```
// store the image sizes in an array
$img_sizes = array( 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large', 'full' );

// grab the URL for each image size and store in a variable
foreach ( $img_sizes as $img_size ) {
    ${ 'img_src_' . $img_size } = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_image, $img_size );
}




echo '<style type="text/css"> 

    .featured-image {

        width: 100%;        
        min-height:350px; 
        background-image: url(' . esc_url( $img_src_medium[0] ) . ');
    }


    @media screen and ( min-width: 400px ) {
        .featured-image {
            background-image: url(' . esc_url( $img_src_large[0] ) . ');
        }
    }

    @media screen and ( min-width: 1000px ) {
        .featured-image {
            background-image: url(' . esc_url( $img_src_full[0] ) . ');
        }               
    }


</style>';

endif;
 };


add_action( 'wp_head', 'home_case_number' );
```

So do I go about this by getting the meta ID of the background image?  Or the attachment ID?  I don't know how to do either at this point.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

1) The CMB "plugin" saves the attachment ID as as another meta key by adding "_id" to the end of it, so I used that to get the attachment ID, and 
2) I had variable scope issues.  As soon as I called my global variable within my function, things started working.  Here's the final code:

```
/**
 * Home Page Case Randomizer
 */

$GLOBALS['_home_case_number'] = rand(1, 3);




function home_case_number() {
    global $_home_case_number;

   if ( is_front_page() ) :  // checks whether this is the home page


    // get the attachment thumbnail ID
            $attachment_image = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_home_case_background_' . $_home_case_number . '_id', true );


    // store the image sizes in an array
    $img_sizes = array( 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large', 'full' );

    // grab the URL for each image size and store in a variable
    foreach ( $img_sizes as $img_size ) {
        ${ 'img_src_' . $img_size } = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_image, $img_size );
    }



    echo '<style type="text/css"> 

        .featured-image {

            width: 100%;        
            min-height:350px; 
            background-image: url(' . esc_url( $img_src_medium[0] ) . '); 
        }


        @media screen and ( min-width: 400px ) {
            .featured-image {
                background-image: url(' . esc_url( $img_src_large[0] ) . ');
            }
        }

        @media screen and ( min-width: 1000px ) {
            .featured-image {
                background-image: url(' . esc_url( $img_src_full[0] ) . ');
            }               
        }


    </style>';

    endif;
 };


add_action( 'wp_head', 'home_case_number' );
```

Hopefully this will help someone else out there.